# Cannot install MongoDB PHP Extension in Docker

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, php-extension, pecl

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.0-fpm-alpine

RUN cp "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN pecl config-set php_ini "$PHP_INI_DIR"

RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}

RUN pecl install mongodb-1.6.1 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

But I get the: `configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location` and suggestion to add the  line to the ini file manually (which I don't want to do for other reasons).

Answer (score 3):

Found out I need to actually do:

`RUN pear config-set php_ini "$PHP_INI_DIR"`